# Running npm linting script does not have the same output as running the script directly

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a `package.json` like so:

```json
{
  "name": "my app",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npx jest",
    "lint": "npx eslint js/**/*"
  }
}
```

When I run `npx eslint js/**/*`, it is working as expected and returns linting errors. However, when I use `npm run lint` it does not show any error when it should, and returns:

```
> myapp@2.0.0 lint
> npx eslint js/**/*
```

On a side note, `npm run test` works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think `npm run npx eslint js/**/*` is redundant.

Try changing `"lint": "npx eslint js/**/*"` to `"lint": "eslint js/**/*"`